# Unable to get the select All checkbox for the p:selectCheckBoxMenu

Tags: jsf, checkbox, primefaces, jsf-2

I am trying to use a `p:selectCheckBoxMenu` (Primefaces component) in the form. However, for some reason I am unable to get the select all checkbox in the control. We are adding this control for the first time inside the form. So we do not have any css class that may hamper wit the rendering of the selectAll checkbox for the control. Can you guys help me with this?

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="multiple" value="#{defaultModel.defaultMethods}" label="Cities" multiple="true" filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith" panelStyle="width:250px"> 
     <f:selectItems value="#{defaultModel.paramEnums}" />
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

[screenshot of the control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKau2.jpg)

Comment: Code Snippet : 
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="multiple" value="#{defaultModel.defaultMethods}" label="Cities" multiple="true"
                               filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith" panelStyle="width:250px">
                  <f:selectItems value="#{defaultModel.paramEnums}" />
               </p:selectCheckboxMenu>

Comment: Showcase works perfectly fine

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I am referring to the checkbox that should have been visible in the besides the filter text box. Is there something else I need to do ?

Comment: Like stated, works perfectly find in the showcase. Find the differences, analyse client side html... debug... investigate...

Comment: So can you also help me with another issue please. Suppose I checked a few items from the SelectCheckboxMenu and then stored that data into the database. I get the selected items in the form of a String Array. When I try to set the String Array object when the page is rendered the next time around, the checkboxes are rendered as unselected. Can you please help me with this problem ?

Comment: New questions in... wel... new questions